# GitLab Runner not creating folders and APK/Unity build

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a CI setup where my GitLab Runner (running on a VM) triggers upon a commit. The YAML looks like this:

```
default:
   tags:
       - unity-powershell

  # Build the project with Unity using the script defined in unity.executeMethod:
unity-build:
    stage: build
    script:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
      - cd "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.17f1\Editor"
      - .\Unity.exe -projectPath $CI_PROJECT_DIR -batchmode -nographics -buildTarget Android -quit -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformBuild -stackTraceLogType Full -logfile 'build.log'
    artifacts:
     paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR\Builds\*.*
```

My PerformBuild script looks like this

```
{
    [MenuItem("Custom Utilities/Build Android")]
    public static void PerformBuild()
    {
        string[] defaultScenes = {
            "Assets/Scenes/SampleScene.unity" };

        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(defaultScenes, "Builds/Build.apk", BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.None);
    }
}
```

If I run the terminal command from the YAML in the VM by entering it in Powershell it works perfectly: a Builds folder gets generated with the built Build.apk inside it (the log file doesn't, somehow). This is the terminal command I run directly:

```
.\Unity.exe -projectPath "C:\GitlabRunner\builds\vV58X3nE\0\xr\androidcitestunity2021" -batchmode -nographics -buildTarget Android -quit -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformBuild -log 'build.log'
```

However, if I trigger this terminal command through the YAML file (by running the pipeline), the VM re-builds the project (indicated by the updated timestamps on e.g. the Unity Library and UserSettings folder), but no folders get generated and no artifacts are created.

I have tried reinstalling Unity, Unity components and the Gitlab-Runner on the VM, as well as working with- and without CI caches, but the issues stays the same. This is the pipeline log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.7.0 (98daeee0)
  on Unity runner vV58X3nE
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on VD921615...
Getting source from Git repository
00:32
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLabRunner/builds/vV58X3nE/0/xr/androidcitestunity2021/.git/
Checking out dbcbd62d as master...
Removing Library/
Removing Logs/
Removing ProjectSettings/BurstAotSettings_Android.json
Removing UserSettings/
git-lfs/3.2.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.18.2)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
05:09
$ $CI_PROJECT_DIR
c:\GitLabRunner\builds\vV58X3nE\0\xr\androidcitestunity2021
$ cd "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.17f1\Editor"
**$ .\Unity.exe -projectPath $CI_PROJECT_DIR -batchmode -nographics -buildTarget Android -quit -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformBuild -stackTraceLogType Full -logfile 'build.log'**
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
Version:      14.7.0
Git revision: 98daeee0
Git branch:   14-7-stable
GO version:   go1.17.5
Built:        2022-01-19T17:11:50+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=14076 revision=98daeee0 version=14.7.0
**WARNING: c:\GitLabRunner\builds\vV58X3nE\0\xr\androidcitestunity2021\Builds\*.*: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload   **                       
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
Job succeeded
```

Honestly I'm quite at a loss after several days of debugging. What could cause the GitLab Runner not to create the final folder and .apk, even though the exact same approach through manual input works perfectly? The main difference is of course the YAML, but when researching online the YAML I use seems the be the recommended approach.